# how scrap categories and subcategory with Scrapy

Tags: json, python-3.x, scrapy, html-parsing

I don't understand how to call a callback for parsing subcategories.

I have the next code as an example.

I want to parsing categories by kegoria, for example:
Main category--->sub_category--->if subcategory have category do parse and add links until we meet the final category that has products then parse product.

I want the json output to look like

```
{
  "url": "Category URL",
  "category_name": "Category name",
  "subcategories": [
    {
      "url": "Subcategory URL",
      "subcategory_name": "Subcategory name",
      "subcategories": [
        
      ]
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
"""
            name_category = item.css('a span::text').get()
            url_category = item.css('a::attr(href)').get()
"""

class CategoryLinkSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "category_link"
    allowed_domains = ["illyushatoys.com.ua"]
    start_urls = ["https://illyushatoys.com.ua/?categoryID=184864"]

    def start_requests(self):
        category_item = {}
        yield scrapy.Request(self.start_urls[0], self.parse, meta={'category_item': category_item})


    def parse(self, response):
        category_item = response.meta.get('category_item')
        links = LinkExtractor(allow=r'.*category/\d+/$', restrict_css='div.inmenu').extract_links(response)
        if not links:
            print('emty_links')
        else:
            for link in links:
                category_item['url'] = link.url
                category_item['title_category'] = link.text
                category_item['subcategories'] = []
                yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_subcategory, meta={'category_item': category_item})

    def parse_subcategory(self, response):
        category_item = response.meta['category_item']
        links = LinkExtractor(allow=r'.*category/\d+/$', restrict_css='div.inmenu').extract_links(response)
        if links:
            for link in links:
                category_item['subcategories'].append({
                    'url': link.url,
                    'title_category': link.text
                })
                yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_subcategory, meta={'category_item': category_item})
            yield category_item
```

Comment: what is wrong with your current implementation?

Comment: In my current implementation wrong generete json, i not undestand how parse like this json: [link](https://prnt.sc/I3vOgSoTrXUc)